# How to style the input type "time"

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to find a source explaining how to fully style the input type "time". I cannot find a single example explaining all of the style attributes!

Only one I've found is:

```
input[type="time"]{
    /**style goes here **/
}
```

Which doesn't help much..

Tried this:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: block;
    width:20px;
    color: red;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

Spinner does not turn red for example.

Comment: If you're looking for a resource that's off-topic. Instead, explain the styling you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what's not working.

Comment: @j08691 I can't try anything because I don't know where to start! (I'd like to style EVERYTHING with the button, hover, on click, the spinner, the clear button etc.)

Comment: I think such element (like the select element) is not meant to be styles and it's handled by the browser

Answer (score 22):

I made some progress styling the input in Chrome/webkit, but I can't figure out how to style anything in Firefox. Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/tryenc/pen/KjrmbE) that I put together on Codepen.

```css
input[type=time] {
  border: none;
  color: #2a2c2d;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  width: 180px;
}

/* Wrapper around the hour, minute, second, and am/pm fields as well as 
the up and down buttons and the 'X' button */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

/* The space between the fields - between hour and minute, the minute and 
second, second and am/pm */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  padding: 19px 4px;
}

/* The naming convention for the hour, minute, second, and am/pm field is
`-webkit-datetime-edit-{field}-field` */

/* Hour */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field {
  background-color: #f2f4f5;
  border-radius: 15%;
  padding: 19px 13px;
}

/* Minute */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field {
  background-color: #f2f4f5;
  border-radius: 15%;
  padding: 19px 13px;
}

/* AM/PM */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
  background-color: #7155d3;
  border-radius: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 19px 13px;
}

/* 'X' button for resetting/clearing time */
input[type=time]::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
}

/* Up/Down arrows for incrementing/decrementing the value */
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" value="13:30"/>
```

I wasn't able to find documentation anywhere. I got this far by inspecting the input's internal DOM, hovering over each element in devTools to see what portion of the UI it corresponded to, then grabbed its `pseudo` attribute.

If you can't currently see the internal DOM, you'll have to expose it by going into Chrome's DevTools Settings, Preferences, Elements and make sure the "Show user agent shadow DOM" option is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

There's another pseudo element: `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` - the clock that shows up in chrome  to allow you picking time using a mouse.

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
   filter: invert(0.5) sepia(1) saturate(5) hue-rotate(175deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="time">
```

Comment: hi
how I can create some of this but background of icon black and icon white

Answer (score 1):

To style the input type `date` and `time` - use the following css -

```
[type="date"] {
  background:transparent url(/assets/images/calendar.png)  97% 50% no-repeat !important;
}
[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}
[type="time"] {
  background:transparent url(/assets/images/clock.png)  97% 50% no-repeat !important;
}
[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}
```