# how to change color of selected numbers in input[type=time]

Tags: html, css, selection

i have this css to change the text selection color which works great:

```
::selection {
  background: #e4d2ba;
}
```

[image: custom text select color in the word Time]

but how can i change the color of the selection of numbers in this time input?

[image: time input numbers still selected in default color]

these dont seem to work for me:

```
input::selection {
  background: #e4d2ba;
}
input[type=time]::selection {
  background: #e4d2ba;
}
```

UPDATE: (regarding possible duplicate)
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544872/how-to-style-the-input-type-time) has a lot of information on styling time inputs, but nothing on changing the selection color

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544872/how-to-style-the-input-type-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the input type "time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544872/how-to-style-the-input-type-time)

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field:focus,
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field:focus,
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field:focus,
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field:focus {
  background-color: #e4d2ba;
}
```

[image: changed selected numbers via webkit field focus background color]

my confusion was based on assuming the numbers were in a `selection` state since it looked like the same color as default selected text to me.  but actually it's the background color of each whole field when focused.  which was also surprising since i had assumed the whole combined time field held the `focus` due to the default blue border